# Linux - CentOS6 - semanage - command not found

Tags: centos, selinux, centos6

I am trying to solve an issue where my HTTPD is denied access to binding custom ports and I believe it has to do with SELinux. Whilst doing some googling I came across some posts where users were typing `semanage` followed with flags and commands to view certain data. In following these posts I too typed in `semanage`, but it's not on my system.

Results of `yum list *semanage*`:

```
Installed Packages
  libsemanage.x86_64 | 2.0.43-4.el6 | @anaconda-CentOS-201106060106.x86_64/6.0
Available Packages
  libsemanage-devel.x86_64 | 2.0.43-4.el6 | base                                    
  libsemanage-python.x86_64 | 2.0.43-4.el6 | base                                    
  libsemanage-static.x86_64 | 2.0.43-4.el6 | base
```

Is the binary available in one of these other packages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The script is in the policycoreutils-python:

```
[root@kerberos home]# rpm -qf /usr/sbin/semanage
policycoreutils-python-2.0.83-19.8.el6_0.x86_64
```

Installing via yum will give you the following:

```
==================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                            Arch                                               Version                                                          Repository                                           Size
==================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 policycoreutils-python                                             x86_64                                             2.0.83-19.8.el6_0                                                updates                                             334 k
Installing for dependencies:
 audit-libs-python                                                  x86_64                                             2.0.4-1.el6                                                      base                                                 56 k
 libselinux-python                                                  x86_64                                             2.0.94-2.el6                                                     base                                                201 k
 libsemanage-python                                                 x86_64                                             2.0.43-4.el6                                                     base                                                 81 k
 setools-libs                                                       x86_64                                             3.3.7-4.el6                                                      base                                                400 k
 setools-libs-python                                                x86_64                                             3.3.7-4.el6                                                      base                                                222 k

Transaction Summary
==================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install       6 Package(s)
Upgrade       0 Package(s)
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks. Apparently yum allows us to do `yum provides /usr/bin/semanage` and it will also list out the packages with the binary.

Comment: Mine turned up in sbin rather than bin; the original command results in "no matches found"; 'yum provides seamanage' also same result but with suggestion to search for '*bin/seamanage', and that one does find matches.  Something about a change in yum version 3.